# Mobile App vs Web App - Apple no longer accepting web apps?

Tags: ios, cordova, mobile

I cannot seem to find this on the web nor on SO or Android SO.

Basically I plan to make a simple, responsive HTML5 mobile website with a PHP/MySQL backend - it is like a diary/track planner. I then wish to use Phonegap, Titanium or some other library to quickly make a the mobile app files and then ship it on the marketplace - there will be no real native features.

I have just heard from my cousin however that Apple is no longer accepting non-native apps - so Phonegap and other apps must use native functions. Is this true?

Comment: _I have just heard from my cousin_ doesn't sound so credible. I'm not aware of any change in Apple's view on solutions like Phonegap or Titanium.

Comment: He is a iOS developer, keeps updated with latest industry changes, he is a pretty credible individual since all his work is iOS primarily driven applications..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Apple's rejection policies, not about programming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple store is still accepting hybrid apps.

From my experience your app will be rejected if you use server side code to generate your page layout. But if you use PHP/MySQL back end as a web service to communicate with a mobile client then you are good to go. This is a rather bed situation because you need to use your hybrid app for page content generation. But at least your app will be accepted.

One more thing your app layout must resemble native iOS apps.

Titanium is still a safe bet because its final result is a native app. In case of Phonegap a good solution is Phonegap + jQuery Mobile or Phonegap + KendoUI (probably the best solution because it UI is closest to native iOS look).

**EDIT :**

For better clarification:

- PHP/MySQL back end as a web service

  All your pages are already inside phonegap app (in assets/www dir) and ajax is used to communicate with web server and retrieve content (for example news lists or single article data). Then that data is used to generate a page content inside a html file.

  Also take a look at my answer (to a similar question): https://stackoverflow.com/a/14166593/1848600
- Phonegap and loading a web app from remote server

  Basicaly you open you remote web app and show it inside phonegap app. Here's an example (also my answer) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13996437/1848600

Comment: can you reference to any document that says Apple won't accept apps that generate their views on server side with html? I have an app that just does this, and it's still active. what you're saying means if i send an update to App Store, they will reject it.

Comment: My apps were rejected numerous times, it all depends how much time Apple employees are willing to spend on app review. Not to mention a whole number of other problems like not be able to use a 3rd party services up to app UI not resembling native app look and feel. I got them all.

Comment: Please can you expand on this point `But if you use PHP/MySQL back end as a web service to communicate with a mobile client then you are good to go.`

Comment: I have added a new content to my answer..

Comment: Does the future look strong for this type of approach? I imagine many websites are taking this approach. It is quicker than building native features. Basically it is like an iframe app or an ajax loading HTML app you're saying??? (good explanation btw thanks)

Comment: Yes there is a future in hybrid apps, more and more developers are opting for this approach. Only negative thing in near future will be a Google ban of 3rd party payment plugins.