# loading html file from web server using phone gap

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, jquery-mobile, app-store

i am planning to develop an hybrid application using phone gap. i want to download html pages,images & other resources from a web server instead of keeping it inside the phone gap application bundle.

1. is it possible to do so
2. is it the right way to avoid updating the application in the App Store frequently or
3. will android, iPhone, windows  reject our application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Yes it is possible with phonegap, nothing can prevent you from loading html file from remote source. Here's my other answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13996437/1848600
2. Unfortunately no. While we can say this is true, every error will brake every available app version, while if you create version by version customers will always be able to use previous ones. Also Apple apps store will ban such app.
3. Android/Win7-8 app will not be rejected, iOS will be rejected immediately. Here's my other answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14436328/1848600, no point in repeating.

Comment: thank you. is it a good idea to develop such a application. our goal was to develop single codebase for PC browsers, tablets & all smart phones.

Comment: It is a good idea as long as you don't upload it ti Apple app store. It will be rejected because if it can run from remote source it can run as a classic web page. In some cases it could pass an app review but your mobile site must not be publicly visible.

Comment: the answer needs an update. iOS shouldn't be rejected. The section 3.3.2 of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement was updated. It can be found here: developer.apple.com/terms. Now is says "...The only exceptions to the foregoing are scripts and code downloaded and run by Apple's built-in WebKit framework or JavascriptCore, provided that such scripts and code do not change the primary purpose of the Application..."

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it's possible.

   you have 2 choices to implement it. simple way is just start on web server url. but, you need a code for including cordova script file that matched target device.

   another way is check & download files.
   In this case, you need to write some code of phonegap for update-check, download contents & change start URL.
2. During you have no reason for changing native code, my answer is Yes.
3. exactly Apple doesn't allow to update app logic without AppStore or load page in web server, but i don't know really it is.